# Makefile Question. [Ubunt, GNUstep, ObjC,]

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, makefile, gnustep

I just made a makefile follow with online tutorials.
http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_1.html

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME = LogTest
LogTest_OBJC_FILES = source.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

once I run the makefile, it showed

```
This is gnustep-make 2.4.0. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
make[1]: GNUmakefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `GNUmakefile'.  Stop.
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

I have checked my GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES setting. I have no idea what this happened.
Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First confirm that you named your makefile "GNUmakefile", and not e.g. "GNUMakefile". If that's correct, instead of typing `make`, try `make -n`; instead of trying to do something, Make will report what it intends to do. The output might look like gibberish, but you can add it to your question (if it's not too long) and we'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks very much. I got it. For GNUStep I need to name my makefile as GNUmakefile.
;-L
It works. Million thanks

Comment: If you came to this conclusion after reading the answer provided by Beta you should mark his answer as being correct.